# Draw smooth line through data points in MATLAB figure

Tags: matlab, figure

I have few MATLAB fig files. All these fig files have same prefix name (Pol_test_) and different suffix name(10,20,30....200). For example, Pol_test_10, Plo_test_20 so on.
Every fig file has five sets of data points. Is there a simple way to connect/join these data points using a line? I want both lines with markers in the result. I don't want to plot them again as it will take a lot of time.
Any suggestions to loop through all the figures?

Comment: If you "don't want to plot them again" how do you expect to plot all of the points? Do you mean you want to retrieve the data from each .fig file and create a new, combined plot? Please create a [mcve], this could include programmatically creating and saving a couple of simple figures, and your expected output from that example.

Comment: I mean, I don not want to go back and create new plots with lines connecting the data points. Instead, I want to use the MATLAB fig files which has data points and add lines running through these points/markers.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a figure such as this, containing several plots with only markers:

```
plot(1:5, [3 6 4 3 5], 'o');
hold on
plot(2:7, [9 6 2 6 9 4], '*');
```

[image]

To have lines connecting the markers, you only need to set the `'LineStyle'`property of each `Line` object that was produced by `plot`. For example, `'-'` will give a solid line, and `'--'` will give a dashed line:

```
ch = get(gca, 'Children');
[ch.LineStyle] = deal('-');
```

[image]